# How to include an ImageView into a Custom Segue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm attempting to create a custom segue where the order of the animation goes

1st UIViewController -> ImageView -> 2nd UIViewController

The code I have works, but for some reason the ImageView is black. I've tried using various images and literal image sources, but it's still black.

Here's some pictures for a better understanding-

> 1 (As the first UIViewController is replaced by the ImageView)

[image: First VC]

> 2 (As the ImageView is replaced by the second UIViewController)

[image: Second VC]

```
/**
 This segue transitions by dragging the destination UIViewController in from the right and replacing the old UIViewController by pushing it off to the left. This Segue also contains an ImageView that is between the two UIViewControllers.
 */
class CustomSegue2: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
        let firstView = self.source.view as UIView!
        let secondView = UIImageView()
        let thirdView = self.destination.view as UIView!

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        // Set properties of secondView
        secondView.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        secondView.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
        secondView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "orangeRedGradient_MESH_tealGreenGradient")

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        let rect = CGRect(x: width + width, y: 0.0, width: width, height: height)
        thirdView?.frame = rect

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(thirdView!, aboveSubview: firstView!)


        // Animation the transition.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstView?.frame = firstView!.frame.offsetBy(dx: -width-width, dy: 0.0)
            secondView.frame = secondView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -width-width, dy: 0.0)
            thirdView?.frame = thirdView!.frame.offsetBy(dx: -width-width, dy: 0.0)
        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this pretty much a standard segue? By that I'm talking about *prepare(forSegue:sender:)* and *performSegue(withIdentifier:Sender:)*. If so, please post that code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`secondView` never appears because at no time do you insert it into the interface.

(I would describe your code overall as completely wrong-headed — if you want a custom transition, you should be writing proper custom transition animation code. But that answers the question of why the image view is "black" — it isn't black, it is completely absent.)

Comment: I figured the answer i was looking for was going to be close to one you gave me. The whole animation should happen in 0.4, the image im using blends the different gradients together. Could you recommend me the proper way to code this though?

Comment: Hi - The proper way is what I said in my answer. Apple provides a whole API for writing custom view controller transition animations. You should use it. See WWDC 2013 video Session 218 for the initial info about this.